# How do I route to a JSON file in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

I am wondering how I create a route to a JSON file in my Laravel project. What I am trying to do is `GET` data from the JSON file, but am unsure of how to create a route that does so. Here is my code:

```
function ajax_get_json(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/products/products.json";
    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = return_data;
            results.innerHTML = data.productName;
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting data....";
}
```

When I try this I get a 404 error, and I am not sure how to create a route to a JSON file. Here is what I have as of now:

`Controller`

```
public function getJSON() {

    return view('products.products.json');
}
```

`Routes`

```
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@getJSON');
```

But this is not working. I suspect that the `url` of `/products/products.json` cannot be correct but I do not know how else I would achieve this considering Laravel is looking for php files. How can I get data from my JSON file by creating the correct type of route, or accessing the correct url?

Comment: Just do `Route::get('/products/products.json', 'ProductController@getJSON');`

Comment: I did this, but just to check I tried to access `mysite.dev/products/products.json` and it cannot find the view

Comment: Do other routes work?

Comment: Yes. It has something to do with how to access JSON files in Laravel. Laravel looks for php files, so I can write something like `products.index` to find the `index.php` file in `products` folder, but if I type `products.products`, it will look for `products.php` instead of `products.json`

Comment: return response()->json([
            'productName' => $productName
        ]);

Comment: @Mohammad would I put this in my controller? I don't just want the product name, I want to access all of the data from JSON file, just kept it at product name for simplicity.

Comment: you read file file.json in controller and send data with response() ....

Comment: What is the view `products.products.json`?  Seems like you should be reading the json file from the controller not returning a view.

Comment: @Devon that is what I'm trying to do. I am simply trying to get the data from that file, but I figured if I can figure out the route for the view, I can figure out the route to get the data.

Comment: There is no view here.  You just want to read the json file.... `return response()->file($pathToFile);`  or in regular PHP, you'd use `readfile()`.  You may need to set the headers to reflect the content type.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sending the json directly from a file you can use the file response from laravel, and if this file is for example in your resource folder then you can use the resource_path helper to get the path

```
return response()->file(resource_path('assets/js/data/filename'));
```

remember to replace the filename with your JSON filename.

you can pass also a header like this

```
return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

if you need to do something with the json content then you could also decode the json from the file

```
$file = file_get_contents(resource_path('assets/js/data/file.json'));
$jsonData = json_decode($file, true));
```

here are links to the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-resource-path
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-responses

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you - I have done this, and can now view the JSON file after putting it in my storage folder, but still cannot figure out the `url` that I need in order to fulfill the AJAX request.

Comment: let me see if I understand your question well, you are having trouble creating the url to the method that returns the file?

Comment: In the `ajax_get_json` method there is a `url` variable that I need to set as the location of the file, but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: ok, in your ajax_get_json function your url has to match you route name, so for example if your route is Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@getJSON'); then your path will be '/products', you dont have to put the product.json, unless you have different json files and want to pass the name of the file as a parameter.

Comment: I tried to match that but get a different error, `(index):75 Uncaught ReferenceError: return_data is not defined at XMLHttpRequest.hr.onreadystatechange`

Comment: you seem to have defined a variable called data to hold the json and are assigning the innerHTML to a variable return_data which is not defined

Comment: but I have not tested your code, my answer was a guideline on how you can get the json data. But you will have to adapt your code to work with the examples

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I forgot to delete that line, it is working fine now!